# How to find records based on matching string content in Mongodb using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a BsonDocument like

```
{

"Code" : "123ACThe three $#^",

. . . . 

}
```

I want to find the records which is having `3AC` anywhere in the string in the field `Code`

*note :-* the characers **AC** should be case insensitive

I am new to mongoDb.How to achieve this ?
Thanks in Advance for replies.

**UPDATE**

I tried this code db.session.find({ "Code": { "$regex": '^(.*?(\b3AC\b)[^$]*)$' } } );

Got this working

**db.session.find({ "Code": { "$regex": '3AC.*'} } );**

Is this the only way ? and how to achieve in C# using native driver ?

Comment: Added an answer that shows how to do this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
db.session.find({Code: /3AC/ })
```

or if you want to ignore case:

```
db.session.find({Code: /3AC/i })
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing a search like that is not generally recommended as an index cannot be used ([as your expression is not anchored to the start of the string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)), in C# you can use the `Query` classes' `Matches` [method](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/?topic=html/5d959658-957e-5086-c9b6-1a75daf12303.htm):

```
Query.Matches("Code", "3AC.*")
```

where `"3AC.*"` represents the regular expression string you're using.

```
MongoCollection<ExampleType> exampleCollection;
var query = Query.Matches("Code", "3AC.*");
foreach (var example in exampleCollection.Find(query)) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the driver's LINQ interface and the driver will build the regular expression for you:

```
var query = sessionCollection.AsQueryable<Session>()
    .Where(s => s.Code.Contains("3AC"));
foreach (var session in query) { ... }
```